# ModelState return false on non required model field

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a simple view model as:

```cs
public record CreateViewModel
{
    [Required]
    [StringLength(
        250,
        ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.",
        MinimumLength = 5
    )]
    public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    [StringLength(
        20,
        ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long."
    )]
    [Display(Name = "Phone Number")]
    public string AlternateContactPhoneNumber { get; set; } = string.Empty;
}
```

But for some reason when my controller run the state as:

```
if (!ModelState.IsValid)
{
    return View(model);
}
```

It is returning that the Phone Number field is required and I do have not a required data annotation on that model property. Any one knows what is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `[ValidateNever]` attribute:

```cs
[ValidateNever]
public string AlternateContactPhoneNumber { get; set; } = string.Empty;
```

---

> [Indicates that a property or parameter should be excluded from
> validation. When applied to a property, the validation system excludes
> that property. When applied to a parameter, the validation system
> excludes that parameter. When applied to a type, the validation system
> excludes all properties within that type.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.modelbinding.validation.validateneverattribute?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

Answer (score 3):

Probably in your project settings in the `.csproj` file, the settings are defined as below

```
<Nullable>enable</Nullable>
```

If you're using `.Net6` and above, this option is `enable` by default, Which makes `string` like [value types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-types) like `int` and others cannot accept `null` value by default. To solve this problem, you can set its value to ‍`disable` or  define the`string` as `nullable` as follows:

```
public string? AlternateContactPhoneNumber { get; set; } = string.Empty;
```

I recommend reading this article: : [Nullable reference types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references)